# Regex analog for lists/sequences

Tags: python, regex, list

I have found it cool that with regular expressions I can get modified strings without having to explicitly loop over the original -- for instance in Python:

```
from re import sub
print sub(r'12', r'twelve', r'12 + 12 = 24')
```

prints

```
twelve + twelve = 24
```

Is there something similar for lists in general? In particular, how it might be used in Python would be most appreciated, but something like this in any language would be cool too.

A sample task I might have would be given a list like

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

replace all occurrences of `0 , 1` with `2` so that I would get:

```
[0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

Of course in this particular case, I could convert the list to a string of digits and then use regex, but I am hoping there is some list analog I can use instead.

Comment: There's no such tool. It would be hard to define the pattern because lists may contain any thing while strings are made only of 1-char strings. But I liked the idea

Answer (score 2):

For this single case:

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
b = []

while a:
    x = a.pop(0)
    if x == 0 and a and a[0] == 1:
        a.pop(0)
        b.append(2)
    else:
        b.append(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a regex analog for list operations.
For some simple cases like yours , you can do this :

1. You can convert the list to str
2. use regex replace to replace elements as per your requirement.
3. use literal_eval  to convert the modified string to list again.

Working here : http://ideone.com/tgg3N

```
from re import sub
import ast

myList = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
listStr = str(myList)
myNewStr = sub(r'0\s*,\s*1',r'2',listStr)
myNewList = ast.literal_eval(myNewStr)
print str(myNewList)
```

But that is not a good way to do it when you can logically do all the operations on the list by replacing elements from the list instead of doing a regex replace on its string representation .

Comment: what does 0,\s+1 mean? Is it same as 0,1 ?

Comment: @shantanuo `\s` means any whitespace occuring between them. Ideally it should be `\s*` to take care of none or more whitespaces. I have edited my answer as well.